# Type mismatch error in checkSelfPermission method in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to send an SMS from my Kotlin Android app, but I'm having trouble with the checkSelfPermission method. Specifically, I keep getting a type mismatch error and I'm unable to access the Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS permission.

Here's the relevant code:
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))

The error message I'm getting is:
Type mismatch.
Required: Boolean
Found: Int

I have tried various method to solve this issue, including creating a new project, making sure that the SEND_SMS permission is defined. but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried to check the SEND_SMS permission using checkselfpermission function which is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare it with `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`, like so:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```